# Trying to calculate the probability of a losing streak given the sample and number of consecutive losses

Tags: probability

As the title suggests. I am trying to calculate the probability of a losing streak given the sample and number of consecutive losses. I have tried doing this with excel (picture below) and I am not sure if it is done correctly.

[image: Losing Streak Probability]
[image: Losing Streak Probability - Formula]